# How do I validate various file upload and other checks before completion

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to upload a mxf file and check for the file upload status and other quality check statuses like below before completion.

```
`Uploading...
Checking...
File check...
Video check...
Audio check...
Completed.`
```

All these statuses come up at different time one following the other like in the snapshow below. What is the best way to validate this using cypress?`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just suggest to put them all after each other. It keeps your test readable. So you could just simple do this:

```js
cy.contains('Uploading...')
cy.contains('Checking...')
cy.contains('File check...')
cy.contains('Video check...')
cy.contains('Audio check...')
cy.contains('Completed.')
```

Or if you want to check for it in a specific element:

```js
cy.contains('element_name', 'Uploading...')
cy.contains('element_name', 'Checking...')
cy.contains('element_name', 'File check...')
cy.contains('element_name', 'Video check...')
cy.contains('element_name', 'Audio check...')
cy.contains('element_name', 'Completed.')
```